# Bold Letter Within Specific Cell in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to print bold letter in specific cell, how can I write specific letter in bold format within a specific cell in `fpdf`?

Comment: Do you have code you are currently using for this injection? Can you please post any relevant php code? @Jack

Comment: have you checked out the fpdf documentation for fonts->styling?
http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm

Comment: thanks for solve this

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the fpdf documentation for fonts->styling? fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm